# How to Build a Chat App using Flutter and mySQL

Tags: mysql, firebase, flutter

I'm trying to build a chat mobile app using Flutter and MySQL. But so far most of resources and tutorials are using firebase. My reason of using MySQL is because I have a web application that connect to MySQL and currently working on the mobile application part.

Is it possible to build a chat mobile app using MySQL instead of Firebase?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a database by your favorite hoster.
2. fill in all the informations for connecting to your database in a file, for example call it **db.php**:

> ```
> <?php
>     $dns = ‘mysql:host=localhost;dbname=enter-database-name’;
>     $user = ‘enter-username’;
>     $password = ‘enter_the_password_of_your_database’;
>     try{
>      $db = new PDO ($dns, $user, $pass);
>     }catch( PDOException $e){
>      $error = $e->getMessage();
>      echo $error;
>     }
> ```

3. create **get.php** file, fill in following code here:

> ```
> <?php
> require_once('db.php');
> $query = 'SELECT * FROM posts';
> $stm = $db->prepare($query);
> $stm->execute();
> $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
> echo json_encode($row);
> ```

4. create basic app structure, after this you can create the database with the following function:

> ```
> Future getData() async{
>     var url = 'https://disgusted-vapors.000webhostapp.com/get.php';
>     http.Response response = await http.get(url);
>     var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
>     print(data.toString());
>   }
> ```

and call it with:

> ```
> @override
>   void initState() {
>     getData();
>   }
> ```

Code from the following guide:
https://medium.com/@santosenoque.ss/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-mysql-web-server-and-phpmyadmin-e100f47bfb82

Comment: The issue with this approach, is that the conversation won't be in realtime,
pls tell me if a wrong();

Comment: hi, the question was: Is it possible to build a chat mobile app using MySQL instead of Firebase? Sure it is with every type of database. Building a realtime chat functionality won't be the task of a database. For this sockets or webevents would be the right approach. even firebase's firestore isn't able to provide a realtime function. you can go for the mentioned types and if it has to be firebase which is not wanted here from the creator of the question, then you can look for the realtime database of firebase. if the app might get big you will need to use both, the realtime & firestore

Comment: hello @Marcel Dz, you are actually right in your comment but not in your answer, reason be that in you answer you are not approaching it with webevents or sockets and the approach you use is to access it via rest API,

Comment: ...if you must use that approach you have to find away to refresh the chat widget within some certain time interval.

in all, I understand what you are saying, am currently working on an app that need this feature,

Comment: ...once am done i will add to the answer so you understand my view, my perspective

Comment: take a look at this bro https://github.com/duongvanson/flutter-app-chat-online-with-mysql/blob/master/lib/chat.dart

Comment: propably it works, but it's a pretty dirty solution. you always have to do the hard work by a server not by client. this link you provided shows how you do it on client. you will run in several issues with this. it wont work if the app is closes so there is no way to send a push notification. also you always have to make sure the chat partners have the same timezone, if not you will also run in a lot issues. the communication and timestamps has to be done by server not client. also if a client has his smartphone clock different to the chat partner, it wont work in sync.

Comment: check out the approaches from my above message, using sockets for example everything is done by server in realtime and you have a nice and clean fundamental without any work on the client except fetching the data